# jQuery select DOM Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML structure...

```
<div class="comments">
    <div class="like_result"></div>
    <div class="all_comments" style=" max-height: 300px;   overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">      
    </div>
    <form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" class="send_comment">
        <div class="row">                       
            <div class="col-md-10">                         
                <textarea name="comment_message" class="form-control comment_text" placeholder="Write your comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="hidden" class="post_id" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post->posts_id; ?>">
            </div>                      
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, on Ajax successfully call I want to load the data to the class called `all_comments` with the following code:

```
$(this).parents(".comments").find(".all_comments").html(data);
```

but It's not loading or working.

Can you tell me how can I do this?

**Updated:**

jQuery code I am using :

```
$(".send_comment").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    var that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'save-comment.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dattType : 'html',
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function ( data ) {
            // that.prev(".all_comments").append( data );
            // that.find(".comment_text").val(' ');
            // refresh();   
            $(this).parent(".comments").next(".like_result").next(".all_comments").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: We need to see the context surrounding that line of JavaScript. Without it, we cannot know what `this` refers to, what `data` is, if the `$.ajax` is being properly awaited, etc. Are there errors in console? If you `console.log(data)` before using it, is it populated with the value you're expecting?

Comment: I have updated my question with my new tried code.

Comment: Your `success` function re-scopes `this`. You've already got the variable (`var that`) stored - you just need to use `that.parents(".comments")...` instead of `$(this).parent(".comments")`.

Comment: Your commented code should give you a good idea of what you should be doing. (Hint: try using `that`, not `$(this)`)

Comment: can u try with this code? `that.closest(".comments").find(".all_comments").html(data)` , parents() sometimes make strange things .. could it be the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context where you're using `$(this)`, it no longer refers to the element triggering the initial event. Any time you declare a new function, `this` changes meaning. <sup>*(Arrow functions are an exception to this)</sup>

I would've suggested storing the element as a variable before `this` changes scope, but you're actually already doing that:

```
var that = $(this);
```

You just need to use it. I'm also changing your selector a bit to be more adaptable to HTML changes you may decide to make down the road.

```
that.closest(".comments").find(".all_comments").html(data);
```

Word of advice: If you're storing a jQuery element, prefix the variable with a dollar sign. No functional difference, but an accepted convention I'd suggest following for readabllity.

```
var $that = $(this);
```

```
$that.closest(".comments").find(".all_comments").html(data);
```

Comment: I see there is no error on the console log but not data is showing after the successfull call. but I can see that data is returned :(

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` in your `success:` function, what does it appear as?

Comment: it's returned : <p><b>Foyez Ahmed</b> <br/> new comment</p><div class='comment_like'><span class="reaction_2" id="like1seperator1" rel="like"><i class="likeIconDefault" ></i>Like</span></div>

Comment: Just Awesome. Working fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `that` variable and `siblings()` selector

```
that.siblings('.all_comments').html(data);
```

**Note:** `this` wont work in ajax callback

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-primary").click(function(){
//after ajax 
var $that = $(this);
var data='<div>Results</div>';
$(this).parent().parent(".comments").find('.all_comments').html(data);
});
});
```

You can test it on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8buhm05/4/).
I have tried and work fine for me.

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $(this), you can save a reference the $(".send_comment") selector. That way you don't need to re-select it, and also use it in the response to find the other selector (relative to it):

```
var sendComment = $(".send_comment");
sendComment.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    var that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'save-comment.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dattType : 'html',
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function ( data ) {
            // that.prev(".all_comments").append( data );
            // that.find(".comment_text").val(' ');
            // refresh();   

           sendComment.parent('.comments').first('all_comments').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How about a little explanation, rather than just giving him the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="comments">
    <div class="like_result"></div>
    <div class="all_comments" style=" max-height: 300px;   overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">      
    </div>
    <form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" class="send_comment">
        <div class="row">                       
            <div class="col-md-10">                         
                <textarea name="comment_message" class="form-control comment_text" placeholder="Write your comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="hidden" class="post_id" name="post_id" value="">
            </div>                      
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
<script>

    $(".send_comment").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    var that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost/save-comment.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dattType : 'html',
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function ( data ) {
            // that.prev(".all_comments").append( data );
            // that.find(".comment_text").val(' ');
            // refresh(); 
            $(that).parent().find('.all_comments').html(data);
        }
    });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a built-in way to pass `this` (or any other element) to your ajax callbacks, it is the [`context`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings) option, so if you want to pass `.send_comment` to the `success` callback, use `context : this` and that way you will be able to use `$(this)` as a reference to that `.send_comment` class.

```
$(".send_comment").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url : 'save-comment.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'html',
    context : this, // pass "this" here
    data : $(this).serialize(),
    success : function ( data ) {
        // that.prev(".all_comments").append( data );
        // that.find(".comment_text").val(' ');
        // refresh();   
       // $(this) now will refer to the current selected ".send_comment" element     
       $(this).parent(".comments").next(".like_result").next(".all_comments").html(data);
    }
  });
});
```